# app build hanging when after dependencies are resolved

Tags: android, dart, flutter

[image]

I was running a project in windows and was working however when I switch to Ubuntu 18.04,any time I try to run it gets stuck like after the last line in the above picture.

output of flutter doctor -v
[image]

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v` to your question.

Comment: Please add logs and code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: I assume the `flutter doctor` output provides enough information about how to fix the problem.

Comment: I think it is happening due to google-services dependency latest version 4.0+ in `build.gradle(project)`